# Finding max element in a list in SML

Tags: list, sml, fold

I am trying to find the the greatest value in a list using Standard ML. I need to use the given fold function:

```
 fun fold f [] base = base
   | fold f (x::xs) base = fold f xs (f x base);
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
fun max (x::xs) = fold (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else 0) x (x::xs);
```

I have 0 in there because if the list is empty then I need to return 0;
This is only part of another function that I need to define, but I'm struggling with the fold part.

Answer (score 3):

In your definition of the `fold` function, you require that the function `f` must take it's arguments in curry form, that is: `f 1 1`  instead of `f(1,1)`.

As I understand, then your definition of the `fold` function is the right one. Thus you need to make proper changes to the anonymous function in the `max` function.

In SML, currying is actually just syntactic sugar. For example:

```
fun foo a b = a+b
```

would end up as (after desugaring):

```
val rec foo = fn a => fn b => a+b
```

It is also seen that the two functions has the same type:

```
- fun foo a b = a+b;
val foo = fn : int -> int -> int
- val rec foo = fn a => fn b => a+b;
val foo = fn : int -> int -> int
```

Thus the anonymous function must be define somewhat along the same lines.

Also you have mixed the arguments to `fold`. In the last part of the `max` function, you are giving the two last arguments in the reverse order.

The last problem is that your anonymous function returns 0. This screws with the invariant of you anonymous function and makes it fail in some cases. For example:

```
max [1,4,65,7,6];
```

Try to figure out why yourself.

If you really *need* to return 0 if the input list to `max` is empty, then you should pattern match that case. This also fixes the warning about "match nonexhaustive", and is the correct place to do it.

```
fun max [] =  0
  | max (x::xs) = fold (fn a => fn b => if a > b then a else b) (x::xs) x;
```